# Zip method with for loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-zip

I am trying to get the following output from 4 different lists, I need to call an address_machine method and zip the items form the list and use a for loop to iterate over the new list then print them on a new line --> EXPECTED OUTPUT below:

```
["T Cruise","D Francis","C White"]
["2 West St","65 Deadend Cls","15 Magdalen Rd"]
["Canterbury", "Reading", "Oxford"]
["CT8 23RD", "RG4 1FG", "OX4 3AS"]
```

My method looks like this:

```
def address_machine(name, street_address, town, postcode):
    address = "{0},{1},{2},{3}".format(name, street_address, town, postcode)
    return address

print([address_machine(name, street_address, town, postcode) for name, street_address, town, postcode in
       zip(["T Cruise", "D Francis", "C White"], ["2 West St", "65 Deadend Cls", "15 Magdalen Rd"],
           ["Canterbury", "Reading", "Oxford"], ["CT8 23RD", "RG4 1FG", "OX4 3AS"])])
```

This is posing a problem as the output I get looks like this and its all on one line:

```
['T Cruise,2 West St,Canterbury,CT8 23RD', 'D Francis,65 Deadend Cls,Reading,RG4 1FG', 'C White,15 Magdalen Rd,Oxford,OX4 3AS']
```

How do I need to write this Python adress_machine function to get the expected output?

Comment: what's your expected output? Your function seems to be running fine to me

Comment: I need each list printed on a new line, and I am getting them all on one line, I have updated the question showing expected output.

Comment: Why use zip here?

Comment: It's a requirement in the task to zip items from the list.

Comment: use normal `for`-loop instead of creating list comprehension. Or assign list to variable (instead of printing it) and use another `for`-loop to print every element from list in separated line - or convert list to single string using `"\n".join(list)`

Comment: I'm a rookie, can you please show in an answer how I can get the expected output as you suggest.

Comment: and if you want expected result then you should use `address_machine to convert it to list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use normal `for`-loop

```
for name, street_address, town, postcode in zip(["T Cruise", "D Francis", "C White"], ["2 West St", "65 Deadend Cls", "15 Magdalen Rd"],
       ["Canterbury", "Reading", "Oxford"], ["CT8 23RD", "RG4 1FG", "OX4 3AS"]):

     print([name, street_address, town, postcode])
```

or first create list with all elements and later `for`-loop to display it

```
data = [[name, street_address, town, postcode] for name, street_address, town, postcode in zip(["T Cruise", "D Francis", "C White"], ["2 West St", "65 Deadend Cls", "15 Magdalen Rd"],
       ["Canterbury", "Reading", "Oxford"], ["CT8 23RD", "RG4 1FG", "OX4 3AS"])]

for item in data:
    print(item)
```

---

And don't understand why you use function `address_machine()` which convert list to string if you expecte result with lists.

Comment: You solved it, thanks. This question got a minus 2 though so I dunno if they will delete it, hats off though furas, thanks.

Comment: your `address_machine` converts list to string without `[ ]` and `" "` - so if you want it to get result as in your question then you would have to use `'["{0}", "{1}", "{2}", "{3}"]'`

Answer (score 1):

Change your address_machine function to:

```py
def address_machine(name, street_address, town, postcode):
    return "{0},{1},{2},{3}\n".format(name, street_address, town, postcode)
```

You have to return an additional newline. And direct return instead of first defining a variable makes the code shorter !